# PyCharm on Launcher running as Sudo

Tags: 16.04, launcher, sudo, pycharm

So I can run PyCharm fine from terminal as Sudo, I have followed the guide to get it running off the launcher but it is not running as Sudo.  Any idea?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: the "guide" is not designed to run PyCharm as sudo.  It's actually designed to be run in userspace; to make it always run as sudo you have to create the launcher using PyCharm's built in "create Desktop launcher" function, find that file, and then edit it accordingly.  (`sudo` also won't work in the GUI, you need whatever the graphical equivalent of `pkexec` is)

Comment: All of my libraries seem to only run as sudo (caffe, cuda etc) so how can I run the pycharm as sudo via not using the terminal

Comment: I give you the solution here - you have to go add the launcher after running pycharm in userspace, then find the launcher file it creates, and then edit it to change the command to what you need it to be (though `sudo` won't work, you need the `pkexec` instead)

Comment: I have composed an answer for almost identical case, see [debugging-in-pycharm-with-sudo-privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299509/debugging-in-pycharm-with-sudo-privileges/44640074#44640074)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found my jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop and used gksudo

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm Community Edition
Icon=/usr/lib/pycharm-community/bin/pycharm.png
Exec= gksudo -k -u root "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce
```

Comment: where is that `jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop` file in ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

> @sourav, you can get the icon file from

`/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop`

> Then you can open it using:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
```